# How change stdout in python

Tags: python, dictionary, stdout

I have the following method that is supposed to give me back a json response, but then printing out the update it returns an error, can some help for me to print the output.

```
def GetUpdates(self):
    try:
        URL = URL
        r = requests.get(url = URL)
        updates = r.json()
        print (updates)
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
```

But When I print (updates) I get the following error 
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9'

This is the actual response :

```
{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":x,
"message":{"message_id":x,"from":{"id":x,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"x","last_name":"x","username":"Guti\u00e9rrez","language_code":"x"},"chat":{"id":x,"first_name":"x","last_name":"Guti\u00e9rrez","username":"x","type":"private"},"date":1543197161,"text":"max"}}]}
```

Comment: are you on python2.7?

Comment: it is python 3.6

Comment: Try `json.loads(r.content.decode("utf8"))`

Comment: Thank you that worked, now what could be the solution if it was python 2.7 ?